# Only numbers in textbox not greater than account balance

Tags: php, html

I am working on a bitcoin website, and every user has an account balance that looks like this: 1.26584000 or 0.00032568. Note that there are always 8 digits after the decimal.

Now I want users to fill in a textbox with an amount of bitcoins, but this textbox may only contain numbers, and if the number is greater then the account balance it should automatically replace with their maximum available balance.

The account balance is stored in a php variable ($balance) as a string like this:

```
$balance = number_format((float)$activeUser['balance'], 8, '.', '');
```

The current textbox I have looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control col-md-10 input-lg" type="text" value="0.00000000" />
```

I already found some solutions with Javascript but I couldn't get the result how I wanted it to be.

Comment: what is your expected outcome and what problem you are facing with java-script code?

Comment: I just want to receive a (decimal) number that is between 0 and the users balance. I want to use this number to store in the database, that isn't important, it's only that the user can't make a mistake with wrong inputs.

Comment: The problems with the min="" and max="" is that it didn't work with decimals. And when i tried with javascript I got the same problem with decimals. Unfortunately I don't have this code anymore.

Comment: correct answer is below. check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply compare two values and find it's minimum:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var accountMax = (Math.random() * 10).toPrecision(8);
  console.log('Account balance: '+accountMax);
  
  $('#value-input').change(function () {
    var inputed = parseFloat($(this).val()).toPrecision(8);
    
    $(this).val(Math.max(0, Math.min(inputed, accountMax)).toPrecision(8));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
BitCoinHacker3000: <input type="text" value="0.00000000" id="value-input"/>
```

Comment: it's nice, but I'd like to point out that given this is dealing with people's finances, the OP should consider server-side validation in PHP as well. Client-side is nice for user-friendliness but it's very easy to bypass it. So the PHP code receiving the postback should also check that the text box contents aren't larger than the maximum available balance, and if so, give an error message so the user can amend.

Comment: @ADyson You are right, but if you wish to validate input on every key press, than it's better to first rely on simple JS validation and only than pass info to PHP validation with deeper rules.

Comment: The input is ofcourse validated at server-side. But it's only for user-friendliness. The code above works how I wanted it to be, but is there an option to use the javascript code only for 1 textbox? I am not that good with javascript.

Comment: @LesleyPeters Replace selector of `input` with some more specific. Like `#value-input` in updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, have it how I wanted it to be!

Comment: The code returned more then 8 decimals if I entered 0.06 for example. I have replaced .toPrecision(8) to .toFixed(8) and now it always returns 8 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

call the function on key press/ on blur even and compare the value the user entered value with the account balance value and replace it with your default value like maximum limit of the user

```
if (usersvalue > accountbalance) {
      $('#valuetextbox').val=accountbalance;
     /* this is used to replace the value use the id or class selector to replace the value */
 }
```